# Creating a trigger : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

It seems to me like everything is ok with the syntax yet I get the error.

Please note: I am creating the trigger, by copy pasting this code in the `mysql` console. Not sure if this matters.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_nse_fo_insert AFTER INSERT
ON NSE_FO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE settle_orders_data VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE delimiter_pos INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE start_pos INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE fill_id VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE if_settled VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE units_settled INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE temp_diff INT DEFAULT 0;

CALL settle_trade_orders(NEW.FillId, NEW.SymbolName, NEW.TransactionType, NEW.AccountName, NEW.TradeDateTime, CAST(NEW.FillSize AS UNSIGNED), NEW.FillPrice, settle_orders_data);

settling_loop: LOOP

SET start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1;
SET delimiter_pos = LOCATE(',', settle_orders_data, start_pos);

IF delimiter_pos = 0 THEN
    LEAVE settling_loop;
END IF;

SET temp_diff = delimiter_pos - start_pos;
SET fill_id = SUBSTRING(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff);

SET start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1;
SET delimiter_pos = LOCATE(',', settle_orders_data, start_pos);
SET temp_diff = delimiter_pos - start_pos;
SET if_settled = SUBSTRING(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff);

SET start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1;
SET delimiter_pos = LOCATE(',', settle_orders_data, start_pos);
SET temp_diff = delimiter_pos - start_pos;
SET settled_count = SUBSTRING(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff);

-- settle in NSE_FO table
-- UPDATE NSE_FO
-- SET Settled=if_settled, settled_units=settled_count
-- WHERE FillId=fill_id;
END LOOP settling_loop;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Below is the error that I see

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IF;
>
> SET temp_diff = delimiter_pos - start_pos; SET fill_id =
>   SUBSTRING(settle_o' at line 19

I am not sure what are the syntax issues around those lines?

**Update**: Removed `IF` statement entirely. Another error throws.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff); SET
>   start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1; ' at line 17. Removed IF entirely.

Comment: @Stivan I removed it and tried to create the trigger again. Exact same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last answer was barking up completely the wrong tree, as such I've removed it.

This code runs for me without error, take care with the commented statements as I don't want you to `DROP` NSE_FO by accident.

Edit: This seems to have been a copy/paste error between the text editor and console. Not sure how this occurred however I've found [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (on Windows) to be very stable in the past.

Regards,

James

```
USE test;

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NSE_FO;
CREATE TABLE NSE_FO (FillId BIT, SymbolName BIT, TransactionType BIT, AccountName BIT, TradeDateTime BIT, FillSize BIT, FillPrice BIT);
*/

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_nse_fo_insert;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_nse_fo_insert AFTER INSERT
ON NSE_FO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE settle_orders_data VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE settled_count VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE delimiter_pos INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE start_pos INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE fill_id VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE if_settled VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE units_settled INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE temp_diff INT DEFAULT 0;

CALL settle_trade_orders(NEW.FillId, NEW.SymbolName, NEW.TransactionType, NEW.AccountName, NEW.TradeDateTime, CAST(NEW.FillSize AS UNSIGNED), NEW.FillPrice, settle_orders_data);

settling_loop: LOOP

SET start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1;
SET delimiter_pos = LOCATE(',', settle_orders_data, start_pos);

IF delimiter_pos = 0 THEN
    LEAVE settling_loop;
END IF;

SET temp_diff = delimiter_pos - start_pos;
SET fill_id = SUBSTRING(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff);

SET start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1;
SET delimiter_pos = LOCATE(',', settle_orders_data, start_pos);
SET temp_diff = delimiter_pos - start_pos;
SET if_settled = SUBSTRING(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff);

SET start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1;
SET delimiter_pos = LOCATE(',', settle_orders_data, start_pos);
SET temp_diff = delimiter_pos - start_pos;
SET settled_count = SUBSTRING(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff);

-- settle in NSE_FO table
-- UPDATE NSE_FO
-- SET Settled=if_settled, settled_units=settled_count
-- WHERE FillId=fill_id;
END LOOP settling_loop;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried that. There is another error that comes up. `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(settle_orders_data, start_pos, temp_diff);

SET start_pos = delimiter_pos + 1;
' at line 17`. Removed `IF` entirely. And still the above error persists.

Comment: apologies, my answer was completely wrong, will either delete or update it depending on how far we get. I can create your trigger on my side if I define the variable `settled_count` and remove the line with the stored procedure. Will take a look at the code around the procedure.

Comment: Have amended my answer

Comment: Then does it have to do with the way I create the trigger? I create it by copy pasting the code in `mysql` console. Are you using some tool to create the trigger?

Comment: No, MySQL workbench but have just run this on the command line with no problems. Does my script return the same error on your machine?

Comment: Ok. Version of `mysql`? I am using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`. May be a upgrade or downgrade might help?

Comment: Here's my version: Server version: 5.7.11-4-log Percona Server (GPL), Release '4', Revision '5c940e1', also using Debian OS Before you go to extremes be sure to rule out any white space errors through copying and pasting from outside your console - its strange the way the error has jumped to a different area of the code after removing the `IF`. If I copy exactly whats in my answer, it works on my server.

Comment: If I copy paste your code, it works! Wow, this is new to me - white space errors.

Comment: Thanks, please accept the answer if useful, sorry for the runaround.